# How to Horizontally Scroll Images In Single Line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sort of basic carousel of images. My question is: how can I get all my slides to display in one line and get them to scroll horizontally instead of vertically?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/3f7fcspL/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    overflow: auto;
}

#carousel .slide {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: you are missing: white-space: nowrap; in your #carousel css class.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply add `white-space:nowrap`

```css
#carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    
    overflow: visible;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#carousel .slide {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use "overflow: auto" if you need a scroll inside a screen.